# Programming a QQ plot

Tags: r, visualization

I have a sample of math test scores for male and female students. I want to draw QQ plot for each gender to see if each of them is normally distributed. I know how to draw the QQ plot for the overall sample, but how can I draw them separately?

Comment: Could you provide a  short self contained example (https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Reproducibility) showing what your data looks like, what you've tried and what happened ? (as a start, if you can produce a plot for your whole dataset, try using subset to split it and use the same code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using `base` graphics:

```
scores <- rnorm(200, mean=12, sd=2)
gender <- gl(2, 50, labels=c("M","F"))
opar <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))
for (g in levels(gender))
  qqnorm(scores[gender==g], main=paste("Gender =", g))
par(opar)
```

A more elegant `lattice` solution then:

```
qqmath(~ scores | gender, data=data.frame(scores, gender), type=c("p", "g"))
```

See the on-line help for `qqmath` for more discussion and example of possible customization.

Comment: the `ggplot2` alternative is `stat_qq`

Comment: You can use `interaction` in `qqmath` if you have several factors, to get distribution of each interaction. E.g. `qqmath(~ response | interaction(factor1,factor2), data=data, type=c("p", "g"))`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you have a QQplot method offered by the OpenTURNS Library [see doc here](https://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/user_manual/_generated/openturns.VisualTest_DrawQQplot.html?highlight=visualtest#openturns.VisualTest_DrawQQplot). Here is an example.

In a first step, we generate a random sample of size 300 from a Uniform distribution.

In a second step, we consider that we do not know where this sample comes from and try to fit a Normal distribution and a Uniform distribution.

In a third step, we draw the QQPlot of ;the sample against each of the fitted distributions in order to "see" which one is the best

1st step:

```
import openturns as ot
from openturns.viewer import View
    
distribution = ot.Uniform(-1, 1)
sample = distribution.getSample(300)
```

2nd step:

```
fitted_normal = ot.NormalFactory().build(sample)
fitted_uniform = ot.UniformFactory().build(sample)
```

3rd step:

```
QQ_plot1 = ot.VisualTest.DrawQQplot(sample, fitted_normal)
QQ_plot2 = ot.VisualTest.DrawQQplot(sample,fitted_uniform)
    
View(QQ_plot1)
View(QQ_plot2)
```

As expected, the fitted Uniform is more adapted to the sample the Normal which has bigger error at both ends of the domain.

[image]
[image]